# Problems using constructors and getting methods for another class

Tags: java, constructor

So i keep getting errors when i try to run the user class saying double is required an no arguments are found. I'm getting errors on lines 17, 40, 42, 44, 46 and 48. They're all errors which say doubles are required. Answers in plain English would be appreciated.

My main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ElectricityCalculatorUser {

    //Main method

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        ElectricityCalculator myCalculator = new ElectricityCalculator();  

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Input the initial reading 
        double initialReading;
        System.out.print ("What is the inital reading on your electricity meter in kwH? ");
        initialReading = input.nextDouble ();

        //Input the final reading
        double finalReading;
        System.out.print ("What is the final reading on your electricity meter in kwH? ");
        finalReading = input.nextDouble ();

        //Input the number of days
        //between readings
        double numberOfDays;
        System.out.print ("How many days have passed between your initial and final reading? ");
        numberOfDays = input.nextDouble ();

        //Calculations
        double totalElectricityUsed = myCalculator.totalElectricityUsed();
        System.out.print ("Total electricity used = " + totalElectricityUsed);
        double costOfElectricity = myCalculator.costOfElectricity();
        System.out.print ("Cost of electricity = " + costOfElectricity);
        double standingCharge = myCalculator.standingCharge();
        System.out.print ("Standing charge = " + standingCharge);
        double costBeforeVAT = myCalculator.costBeforeVAT();
        System.out.print ("Cost before VAT is added = " + costBeforeVAT);
        double VAT = myCalculator.VAT();
        System.out.print ("Cost of VAT = " + VAT);
        double totalCost = myCalculator.totalCost();
        System.out.print ("Total cost = " + totalCost);
        }   
}
```

My class with all the methods:

```
public class ElectricityCalculator {

    //Attributes
    private double initialReading;
    private double finalReading;
    private double numberOfDays;

    //Constructors
    public ElectricityCalculator (double ir, double fr, double nod) {
        initialReading = ir;
        finalReading = fr;
        numberOfDays = nod;
        }

    //Calculating total electricity used
    public double totalElectricityUsed () {
        return finalReading - initialReading;
        }

    //Calculating cost of electricity
    public double costOfElectricity () {
        return totalElectricityUsed * 0.175;
        }

    //Calculating standing charge
    public double standingCharge (double numberOfDays) {
        return numberOfDays * 0.25;
        }

    //Calculating cost before VAT is added
    public double costBeforeVAT (double costOfElectricity, double standingCharge) {
        return costOfElectricity + standingCharge;
        }

    //Cost of VAT
    public double VAT (double costBeforeVAT) {
        return costBeforeVAT * 0.05;
        }

    //Total cost of electricity used 
    //including VAT  
    public double totalCost (double costBeforeVAT, double VAT) {
        return costBeforeVAT + VAT;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java, if you don't write a constructor, a default constructor will be added automatically for you, and this constructor would be `public` and takes no argument.

Something like the following:

```
public ElectricityCalculator () {

}
```

However, when you define any constructors, the default constructor will be removed. And hence, the only constructor that you have in your class is

```
public ElectricityCalculator (double ir, double fr, double nod) {
  initialReading = ir;
  finalReading = fr;
  numberOfDays = nod;
}
```

And therefore

```
ElectricityCalculator myCalculator = new ElectricityCalculator();
```

Doesn't match any constructors.

you can simply create the instance after getting the values required to construct the object

```
ElectricityCalculator myCalculator = new ElectricityCalculator(initialReading, finalReading, numberOfDays);
```

Comment: So how would i fix my code to basically get it to run like i want? Very new to programming so i don't understand your answer too much.

Comment: @John I've edited the answer, it should be clear now

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sleiman Jneidi answer, you are calling functions, but dont provide any parameters, as the method definition demands:

```
double standingCharge = myCalculator.standingCharge();
```

need to be changed to:

```
double standingCharge = myCalculator.standingCharge(10.0); //example for 10 days
```

same problem in the lines 42, 44, 46, 48 of your code

Comment: But i want the user to input 3 values which are in the main method and then for all other methods to be worked out from there.

Comment: thats why you need to use the parametrized constructor `ElectricityCalculator myCalculator = new ElectricityCalculator(initialReading, finalReading, numberOfDays);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public ElectricityCalculator (double ir, double fr, double nod);
public double standingCharge (double numberOfDays);
public double costBeforeVAT (double costOfElectricity, double standingCharge);
public double VAT (double costBeforeVAT);
public double totalCost (double costBeforeVAT, double VAT);
```

The constructor and these methods take arguments but you are trying to call them as if they did not.

For the constructor, you can simply move this line

```
ElectricityCalculator myCalculator = new ElectricityCalculator();
```

to after you take input from the user so you can pass in the arguments.

```
//                                          pass arguments here
//                                     v                v              v
... = new ElectricityCalculator( initialReading , finalReading , numberOfDays );
```

For the other methods you need to be passing in the results of interim calculations. For example `VAT(...)` takes a `costBeforeVAT` which I assume should be the return value of `costBeforeVAT(... , ...)`.

```
double costBeforeVAT = ...;

//                           pass argument here
//                                   v
double VAT = myCalculator.VAT( costBeforeVAT );
```

Note that in some cases you probably do not need these methods to have certain parameters, for example

```
public double standingCharge () {
    return numberOfDays * 0.25;
}
```

because `numberOfDays` was already a member of the class `ElectricityCalculator` and

```
public double costBeforeVAT () {
    return costOfElectricity() + standingCharge();
}
```

because these methods can be called directly instead of asking for their results to be passed in.

Related: ["Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).